# Learn Team Foundation Server 2010 or 2013 as a Tester

Tags: tfs

I am a SQA Engineer and would like to learn complete team foundation server as a tester. Please suggest me any book. Video tutorials will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Check the [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff637362.aspx). It isn't specific to testers. For that read, [Application Lifecycle Management with Visual Studio Team Foundation Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fda2bad5.aspx).

At the onset of learning anything new, I usually watch the most viewed video on YouTube for my term as a primer.

Answer (score 1):

Pluralsight.com has [a lot of video tutorials for TFS](http://www.pluralsight.com/search/?searchTerm=tfs), some are test specific like: http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/microsoft-test-manager-2013

Pluralsight is not free, but the Monthly subscriptions start around 30$, which seems very reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

You can also read this blog: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/

It has been very beneficial for me.